# Alan Storm's Layoutviewer not working after manual install

Tags: module, installation

Magento version: 1.9.2.4

I am currently working through [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-4.html) tutorial, and am trying to install the Layoutviewer module.

I following [the link](http://alanstorm.com/2005/projects/MagentoLayoutViewer.tar.gz) on the page to where I could get the layout viewer, and then used the manual install guide [on this page](http://biodegradablegeek.com/2012/08/installing-alan-storms-layoutviewer-in-magento-works-with-1-7/) to install it.

The module is being detected by magento, and is listed on the `Disable Modules Output` section (it is enabled).

The directory tree for the module is as follows:

```
magento1
    app
        code
            local
                Magentotutorial
                    Layoutviewer
```

I have also made sure that the config file's name and contents are 100% correct.

When I try to use the module (`http://127.0.0.1/magento1/helloworld/index/index/?showLayout=page`) it doesn't work, and just shows me the screen as it was before.

Is there anything I could be missing, or did I perhaps install the module incorrectly?

**edit**

I have already found [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824671/alan-storms-tutorial-on-layoutviewer-magento) that is basically identical to mine, but it's very old so I don't want to comment on in - it did not help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved:

I placed the Layoutviewer in the Magentotutorial directory, but it was supposed to be in it's own (`Alanstormdotcom`) directory.

Both of these solutions worked:

- Move the module to the correct directory or
- Replace all references to Alanstormdotcom/alanstormdotcom to Magentotutorial/magentotutorial